# Strategy won't add to chart - "User cancelled operation"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm working on the following strategy combining the indicators "UT Bot Alerts" and "STC Indicator - A Better MACD [SHK]"

```
//@version=5
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

// Inputs
a = input(1,     title = "Key Vaule. 'This changes the sensitivity'")
c = input(10,    title = "ATR Period")
h = input(false, title = "Signals from Heikin Ashi Candles")

xATR  = ta.atr(c)
nLoss = a * xATR

src = h ? request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off) : close

xATRTrailingStop = 0.0
xATRTrailingStop := src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? math.max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src - nLoss) : src < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? math.min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src + nLoss) : src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? src - nLoss : src + nLoss

pos = 0
pos := src[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? 1 : src[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? -1 : nz(pos[1], 0)

xcolor = pos == -1 ? color.red: pos == 1 ? color.green : color.blue

ema   = ta.ema(src,1)
above = ta.crossover(ema, xATRTrailingStop)
below = ta.crossover(xATRTrailingStop, ema)

buy  = src > xATRTrailingStop and above
sell = src < xATRTrailingStop and below

EEEEEE = input(12, 'Length')
BBBB = input(26, 'stLength')
BBBBB = input(50, 'SlowLength')

AAAA(BBB, BBBB, BBBBB) =>
    fastMA = ta.ema(BBB, BBBB)
    slowMA = ta.ema(BBB, BBBBB)
    AAAA = fastMA - slowMA
    AAAA

AAAAA(EEEEEE, BBBB, BBBBB) =>
    AAA = input(0.5)
    var CCCCC = 0.0
    var DDD = 0.0
    var DDDDDD = 0.0
    var EEEEE = 0.0
    BBBBBB = AAAA(close, BBBB, BBBBB)
    CCC = ta.lowest(BBBBBB, EEEEEE)
    CCCC = ta.highest(BBBBBB, EEEEEE) - CCC
    CCCCC := CCCC > 0 ? (BBBBBB - CCC) / CCCC * 100 : nz(CCCCC[1])
    DDD := na(DDD[1]) ? CCCCC : DDD[1] + AAA * (CCCCC - DDD[1])
    DDDD = ta.lowest(DDD, EEEEEE)
    DDDDD = ta.highest(DDD, EEEEEE) - DDDD
    DDDDDD := DDDDD > 0 ? (DDD - DDDD) / DDDDD * 100 : nz(DDDDDD[1])
    EEEEE := na(EEEEE[1]) ? DDDDDD : EEEEE[1] + AAA * (DDDDDD - EEEEE[1])
    EEEEE

mAAAAA = AAAAA(EEEEEE, BBBB, BBBBB)
mColor = mAAAAA > mAAAAA[1] ? color.new(color.green, 20) : color.new(color.red, 20)

if (buy and mColor == color.green and mAAAAA < 25)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

if (sell and mColor == color.red and mAAAAA > 75)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
```

`UT Bot Alerts` was in `pinescriptv4` but I have converted it to `v5` using the docs and the errors that I was getting.

I have resolved all the errors but some reason I keep getting the following message whenever I try to add the strategy to my chart:
[info message from trading view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB4Jg.png)

**`User cancelled operation`**

I have looked everywhere in the docs. In the errors section of the docs, "cancelled" and "operation" aren't even mentioned.

What am I supposed to do here?

Thank you. Please let me know if there's anything else I can provide to help. This issue seems rather small which is why I was reluctant to ask here but I can't find anything on it anywhere.

Comment: No issues here. Try to create a new indicator and copy your code there.

Comment: @vitruvius I tried creating another strategy and couldn't add to chart again. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by getting a tradingview subscription trial.